# Haskell summarize all paths through a tree

Tags: haskell, summarization, tree-search

I try to summarize ALL paths though a tree that expands every level between 1 and 10 times from the root to the lowest children.
My function walks recursive to all children but I have the problem that when I try to make a List of the nodes and do this lists in a list, I become a List of a List of a List ... of a List.
I think my problem is the combining step And I tried to make a pattern matching method but the method that should  compare the lists when it becomes a lists of lists and should make new lists and compare them if it get's just one way( meets a list with the nodes and not a list with lists)  doesn't work.

Comment: Your (non-working) code would probably make what you've tried a lot clearer :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
summarize :: Tree a -> [[a]]
summarize Leaf = [[]]
summarize (Node a t1 t2) = do
    t <- [t1, t2]
    map (a:) (summarize t)
```

Edit: Note that the above assumes the following definition for `Tree`:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Edit #2: This version of the code might be clearer:

```
summarize :: Tree a -> [[a]]
summarize Leaf = [[]]
summarize (Node a t1 t2) = do
    t       <- [t1, t2]
    summary <- summarize t
    return (a:summary)
```

This version has the nice property that it can be written as a list comprehension:

```
summarize (Node a t1 t2) = [a:summary | t <- [t1, t2], summary <- summarize t]
```

Comment: @rightfold That's not equivalent, though.  Your version wraps the final result in a `return`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Whoops, brainfart. Should pay more attention next time. :)

Comment: @rightfold It's ok.  I made the exact same mistake when writing up the answer the first time. :)

Answer (score 1):

A tree can be represented as a list-monadic-list (a list where there are several options for how it resumes at each point). Then, what you want is simply a fold on this monadic list.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.List.Funcs (repeatM) -- cabal install List
import qualified Data.List.Class as L

exampleTree = L.take 3 (repeatM [0, 1])
```

To see all paths:

```
ghci> L.toList exampleTree 
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

To sum all paths:

```
ghci> L.foldlL (+) 0 exampleTree 
[0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3]
```

Wrt this representation of trees, the [ListTree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListTree) package offers combinators for tree operations (such as DFS/BFS iteration) on trees represented as `ListT []`s.